# In ASP.NET MVC 2, can I deserialize a querystring into an array using the default ModelBinder?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url, modelbinders

In ASP.NET MVC 2, you can use this URL and this controller method:

```
GET http://server/controller/get?id=5

public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

And the ModelBinder will convert the `id=5` querystring to `id = (int) 5` in the method parameter. However, this won't work:

```
GET http://server/controller/get?idlist=1,2,3,4,5

public ActionResult Get(int[] idlist)
{
    ...
}
```

`idlist` will be null in the parameter. Although the parsing for this is pretty trivial, I was wondering if there is a way to either change the method signature or the querystring in order to make the default ModelBinder automatically deserialize arrays/collections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With the default modelbinder, the url should be

```
http://server/controller/get?idlist=1&idlist=2&idlist=3&idlist=4&idlist=5
```

or

```
http://server/controller/get?idlist[]=1&idlist[]=2&idlist[]=3&idlist[]=4&idlist[]=5
```

If you really want to use idlist=1,2,3,4,5, you should have your own binder

Comment: Ouch, I'll just stick to `idlist.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x));`.

Comment: The default modelbinder doesn't support the second example.

Answer (score -1):

This is a little late to the party but I wanted  to  do  exactly the same thing.

You can pass the single string as   {1,2}  and it  the binder will  bind it to an array
e.g

```
<input name="idlist" type="text" value="{163,162}">
```

Answer (score -4):

Here's what I think:

```
public ActionResult Get(int id)
{
   ...
}
```

Should be used as

```
GET http://server/controller/get/5
```

And the idlist can be simply split by comma(,)

Comment: How is your integer id going to contain a comma delimited list ?

Comment: Why don't just make it easier by passing a string list. I think it should be really easy to do that. Am I right?

Comment: This doesn't even remotely answer my question.