# ASP .NET MVC 3 based Facebook app: parse query string array with default model binder?

Tags: .net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3

In a nutshell: Facebook passes my MVC 3 application the following query string after a user selects friends with the fb:request-form control:

> http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/?...&ids[]=100001694177427&ids[]=100001178061757

I assumed the default model binder would parse the ids[] array in the query string and bind it to my ids parameter in the action below:

```
public ActionResult Index(long[] ids)
{
   //...
   return View();
}
```

This previous question appeared to backup my thinking: [In ASP.NET MVC 2, can I deserialize a querystring into an array using the default ModelBinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394165/in-asp-net-mvc-2-can-i-deserialize-a-querystring-into-an-array-using-the-default)

However, I still receive a null value. I've tried every parameter type I can think of, but to no avail. I can see from my controller's ValueProvider that it's definitely coming through (and being parsed as an array), so thought I would post here for ideas before working through the ModelBinder source!

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the model binder expects the parameters to be in this form `http://apps.facebook.com/my_app/?...&ids=100001694177427&ids=100001178061757` without the `[ ]`

Comment: Why MVC3 remove the way to accept square bracket [] in the querystring? I thought, what I remember `ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3` is more practise, standard and compatible than `ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source it appears to be looking for indexes that contain `[0], [1], [2]...` rather than allowing for `[]`. Seems an interesting oversight.

However, you can create a custom modelbinder by doing the following:

```
public class IdList : List<long> { }
```

This is a class to hold our ids

```
public class IdListModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        var x = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("ids[]");

        IdList list = new IdList();
        foreach (var value in (string[])x.RawValue) {
            //replace this with proper validation of values
            list.Add(long.Parse(value));
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

Then in the controller you would do something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(IdList ids) {
    return View();
}
```

In your global.asax you would add the following line to your `Application_Start` method

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IdList), new IdListModelBinder());
```

Comment: Model answer - see what I did there. I'm already using a SmartBinder object to bind generated entities, but added a new one for the Ids and it works a treat. Thanks for your help!

Comment: heh, funny :) glad to be of help

Comment: Why MVC3 remove the way to accept square bracket [] in the querystring? I thought, what I remember `ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3` is more practise, standard and compatible than `ids=1&ids=2&ids=3`?