# ASP.NET MVC: How to create a model that will bind to this POSTed data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I'm having trouble creating a model that will bind to the form data below . The main difficulty I'm having is creating a model that will bind the `filter` (ie: the multi-dimensional array).

This is what I have so far. Can anyone help me to get this model to bind properly?

```
 public class GetPagedRequest
    {
        public int Start { set; get; }

        public int Limit { set; get; }

        public string dir { set; get; }

        public List<FilterRequest> filter { set; get; } //This won't bind properly

    }

    public class FilterRequest
    {
        public string field { set; get; }

        public DataFilterRequest data { set; get; }
    }

    public class DataFilterRequest
    {
        public string type { set; get; }
        public string value { set; get; }

    }
```

[image: Posted Data]

Comment: Could you add the form layout you have currently?

Comment: You already have a model that will bind properly.  The problem is how you are constructing your form in the view.  You need to include that information so we can tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I'm using a third party Javascript Grid controls by Ext JS. I'm not using a form to construct and post the data. http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html

Comment: @burtn1ce Are you trying to fill Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters with the model?  We will need some more specifics on the sencha code you are using to be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

After reading the capabilities of DefaultModelBinder, I saw the problem in the post data.

Before anything, just change the class of the filter property to:

```
public IList<FilterRequest> filter { set; get; } //(IList<T> instead of List<T>)
```

Here is a query string that the DefaultModelBinder will Bind correctly:

```
start=0&limit=5&dir=ASC&sort=noSort&filter[0].field=CompanyName&filter[0].data.type=string&filter[0].data.value=Telus&filter[1].field=VendorName&filter[1].data.type=string&filter[1].data.value=testtest
```

But js is generating this query string:

```
start=0&limit=5&dir=ASC&sort=noSort&filter[0][field]=CompanyName&filter[0][data][type]=string&filter[0][data][value]=Telus&filter[1][field]=VendorName&filter[1][data][type]=string&filter[1][data][value]=testtest
```

Now you can implement your own ModelBinder class, but I think is easier to serialize the object on the client side, just make sure that the content type is properly set. Here is an example made in jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSendPost").click(function () {
            var filterData = {
                "start": 0, "limit": 5,
                "dir": "ASC", "sort": "noSort",
                "filter": [{ "field": "CompanyName", "data": { "type": "string", "value": "Telus" } },
                           { "field": "VendorName", "data": { "type": "string", "value": "testtest" } }]};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ReceivePostFromJson",
                data: JSON.stringify(filterData),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then you only add this line to your Application_Start method in global.asax file:

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

That way the framework will bind correctly the model, and in the action method you'll receive the object

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ReceivePostFromJson(GetPagedRequest g)
    {
```

#### Original Answer

If you could Stringify the json from the control, before posting the filter data, then you could use JavaScriptSerializer to Deserialize the object.

This example is made in jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSendPost").click(function () {
            var filterData = {
                "start": 0, "limit": 5,
                "dir": "ASC", "sort": "VendorName",
                "filter": [{ "field": "CompanyName", "data": { "type": "string", "value": "Telus" } },
                           { "field": "VendorName", "data": { "type": "string", "value": "testtest" } }]};
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/ReceivePostFromJson",
                data: JSON.stringify(filterData),
                dataType: "application/json"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceivePostFromJson()
{
    string jsonStringify = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GetPagedRequest>(jsonStringify);

    return View(obj);
}
```

That way you have the nested objects:
[image: Json MVC Test screenshoot]

Note: In this example if you **remove the function JSON.stringify** (data: filterData,), you'll see on the controller side the query string that produce your problem (filter[0][field]: CompanyName). I don't know if there's a way to recover the json, if it's possible then you don't have to modify the grid control:
[image: JS object made form]

Comment: Why Do you serialize the data?

Comment: JavaScriptSerializer doesn't need the attribute [Serializable], i'll remove it from the answer.

DataContractJsonSerializer does needs [Serializable]

Comment: If you refer to the data in js, is to prevent that the object is transformed into a query string; that way the object is stringify and there's no aditional transformation, then the string can be retrieved on the server side and deserialize.

Comment: Hi Elisa, I had to comment your answer here; I understand your point of view in fact I always encourage using the standards mechanisms of the framework. But in this case the control is a 3rd party control from my point of view the best integration is the one that requiere little modification of the 3rd party components, with the data supplied the framework couldn't deserialize the query string post, that's why I recommend that the object became a JSON string and on the server use another deserializer class in this case "JavaScriptSerializer". That's why I said "If you could Stringify"

Comment: BTW, if you don't want to touch the grid control, you'll have to [implement your own model binder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032337/asp-net-mvc-3-based-facebook-app-parse-query-string-array-with-default-model-b) which is by far more "complicated" than adding a JSON.stringify on js.

Answer (score 0):

I do not support the solution from jherrera:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReceivePostFromJson()
{
    string jsonStringify = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
    var obj = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<GetPagedRequest>(jsonStringify);

    return View(obj);
}
```

if you want to recieve json data from the client on server side you should prepare your client side object to have the save structure like the server side viewmodel. That way the model binder will do its job perfectly when the form is submitted.

code not tested:

```
public ActionResult DeleteXXX(GetPagedRequest pagedRequestViewModel)
{
   // Use AutoMapper or a UI Service to reshape/map your viewmodel to your domain model
   return EmptyResult();
}
```